# Cucumber runner not needed anymore?

Tags: selenium, cucumber

Quick question - since when Cucumber doesn't need any separate runner class with steps glued etc? Nothing else is needed currently after adding JUnit dependency to pom.xml? I've just setup a simple project and as I can see nothing besides chromedriver, step definitions, feature files and Selenium/JUnit/Cucumber dependencies is needed. Was it always like that? Because I remember these projects were uneasy to setup because of that class and few other things. Was I just stupid back then, or did something change and it's easy now?

Comment: Show your pom.xml

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>

Comment: Can you also share which steps are you following to set up the project you mentioned.

Comment: You can try this one.  https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few things have improved! Just not the thing you mentioned.

When you are using the CLI (either directly or through IDEA) Cucumber will search the entire class path for step definitions and feature files. This means that things usually *just work*.

To integrate with JUnit4 you will still need a runner class. However unless you tell it otherwise with `@CucumberOptions` the runner class will look for features and glue in the package and subpackages it is in.

So if you put everything in the right group and in the same package no additional configuration is needed. You should make use of this!

There is a little gotcha when using maven. If you put your feature files in the `src/test/java` folder, maven won't copy them to your class path. Features should always go into `src/test/resources`.

```
~/Projects/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/examples/calculator-java-junit4$ tree
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── io
    │           └── cucumber
    │               └── examples
    │                   └── calculator
    │                       └── RpnCalculator.java
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── io
        │       └── cucumber
        │           └── examples
        │               └── calculator
        │                   ├── RpnCalculatorSteps.java
        │                   └── RunCucumberTest.java
        └── resources
            ├── cucumber.properties
            └── io
                └── cucumber
                    └── examples
                        └── calculator
                            └── basic_arithmetic.feature
```

You can also do the 10 minute tutorial to get a fresh start: https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: Hmm, actually... I honestly didn't create any Runner class and it works with JUnit dependency. 

Comment: I'd like to see you reproduce that in a github repo from scratch.

Comment: There's not much to do tbh. I've just create a Maven project in Intellij, added selenium-java, cucumber-java and junit4-java dependencies to pom, created stepdef class and created a feature file just like you described above. Then I just used imports in stepdef class, instantiated chrome driver (which I put in C:\ and added the location to path in env variables. And then I just run the feature file and it worked. 15 minutes and its done. Maybe Intellij's automatic run configuration took care of the rest? Idk, but There's no Runner class.

Comment: Then I don't think you'll run any tests with JUnit. You are running tests with IDEA and could remove the  CucumberJUnit dependency.

Comment: Yes, you're partially right. Its being run by IntelliJ's run, as I expected, and I can delete Junit dependency (only in terms of running the tests, 'cause then I don't have many testing tools), but I can't delete Cucumber dependency - without it nothing works.

In the end we got to the bottom of this :D Wish it all was so easy and well built when I tried to learn it few years ago...

Comment: Thanks M.P. Korstanje! :)

Comment: No problem. It's open source. You get what your contribute. :D